# How do jQuery animations start from the end?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I'm trying to design a small menu and I really like this code. As you normally know, menus are closed when the page is first loaded. How can I make this animation closed when the page is first loaded? How can I start this animation in reverse?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slide-toggle").click(function(){
            $(".box").animate({
                width: "toggle"
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
.box{
        float:left;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #f0e68c;
    }
    /* Add padding and border to inner content
    for better animation effect */
    .box-inner{
        width: 400px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #a29415;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="slide-toggle">Slide Toggle</button>
    <hr>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</div>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with hidden `.box` by adding `display: none`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slide-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".box").animate({
      width: "toggle"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f0e68c;
  display: none;
}


/* Add padding and border to inner content
    for better animation effect */

.box-inner {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #a29415;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="slide-toggle">Slide Toggle</button>
  <hr>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse
      varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam
      ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</div>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box" style="display:none">
```

When the menu is closed, it adds display: none property to the .box element. You have to add this style property to the .box element in HTML to make it look trapped on boot.